# Single custom post type template not working (single-custom_post_template.php) not working

Tags: single

I've tried manually flushing the permalinks and also tools > permalinks > save but still it's not working! Does any one else have any ideas of what may be breaking it?

Comment: Can you please provide more information, such (as example) your source code of the problematic .php file?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your `single-posttypeslug.php` is not used by the WordPress [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png) has nothing to do with the permalinks (or better said pretty permalinks).

You most probably haven't used the actual slug of your custom post type in the file name. It's the first argument of the [register_post_type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) function call.

Cheers